# capybaraのsave_and_open_pageで開いたページの日本語が文字化けします。

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

capybaraでsave_and_open_pageを使って開いたページが、以下のように日本語のみ文字化けしてしまいます。

[image: 文字化けした様子]

直し方があれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: capybaraのタグを追加しました。

Comment: 閲覧しているHTMLページのcharset(HTMLヘッダのmetaタグ内)と、HTMLファイル自体の文字コードはどうなっていますか？

Comment: 今確認したら、指定されていませんでした。

Comment: はい、それではHTMLファイルの文字コードに合わせてmetaタグを追加した方が良いかと思います。ただ、文字コードは全て UTF-8 に統一しておくのが問題が少なくて良いかとは思いますが。。。

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
とheadに追加したら治りました！ありがとうございます。

Comment: 一応、このサイトの決まり？として、ご自身で問題を解決された場合は、ご自身で問題点と解決の手順を回答することになっているそうです。お手数とは思いますが、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

layouts/application.html.erbのhead内へ

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

を追加したら文字化けが治りました。

Answer (score 2):

HTML header 内に meta http-equiv で charset を指定する場合には headタグ内の先頭に記述するようにしてください。

charset 指定より前に title タグ等で日本語文字列が使われているとブラウザの実装によって文字化けすることがあります。